# My Search feature is broken

Tags: search, fast-search

I don't understand, when I try to go my search url:
[http://server:27252/searchadministration.aspx?appid=e0f019a0-9c5b-40fa-8515-913464d7f3d9]

I get this error:

> [ System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi.RunOnServer[T](CodeToRun`1
>   remoteCode, CodeToRun`1 localCode, Boolean useCurrentSecurityContext,
>   Int32 versionIn)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi.RunOnServer[T](CodeToRun`1
>   remoteCode, CodeToRun`1 localCode, Int32 versionIn)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi.GetContentSources(Int32
>   versionIn)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ContentSourceCollection..ctor(Content
>   parent)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content.get_ContentSources()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.WebControls.ListContentSourcesControl.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ]

What can I do?

Comment: Was it working before? Any hints in the ULS logs?

Comment: nothing in logs :(

Comment: Was it ever working, or suddenly threw an error?

Comment: suddently, I have added a new content sources and... crack

Comment: Have you tried to remove the content source?

Comment: Yes but I cannot access to the page managing content sources... :(

Comment: Try via powershell instead. Unless you want to just recreate the SSA.

Comment: Thanks but how can I do it using powershell?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906563(v=office.15).aspx